# How to change the Baud Rate for bluetooth?

Tags: android, baud-rate

I have a device which keeps dropping my bluetooth headset when I do other bluetooth intensive operations like sending a file via BT to another device. I was thinking that the problem might be that the baud rate is set too low for the device.

By the way, the error log I am having is below:

```
10-12 14:35:17.070 D/KeyguardViewMediator( 2173): wakeWhenReadyLocked(3)
10-12 14:35:17.070 I/power   ( 2173): *** set_screen_state 1
10-12 14:35:17.080 D/PowerManagerService( 2173): setPowerState() wifi is enabled, will reconnect
10-12 14:35:17.310 I/dispd   ( 2030): path:/devices/platform/imx-i2c.0/i2c-0/0-0066/backlight/0-0066
10-12 14:35:17.310 I/InputDispatcher( 2173): Dropped event because input dispatch is disabled.
10-12 14:35:17.340 D/Sensors ( 2173): enable_sensor sensor_type=1, what =0x101
10-12 14:35:17.340 D/Sensors ( 2173): enable..mEnabled=0x1
10-12 14:35:17.340 D/Sensors ( 2173): AccelSensor....setDelay, ms=200,handle=0
10-12 14:35:17.340 D/Sensors ( 2173): AccelSensor....setDelay, mMinPollDelay=0
10-12 14:35:17.340 D/Sensors ( 2173): AccelSensor....setDelay, mMaxPollDelay=0
10-12 14:35:17.340 D/Sensors ( 2173): AccelSensor....setDelay, delay=200,poll_sysfs_file=
10-12 14:35:17.340 D/Sensors ( 2173): AccelSensor....setDelay, ms=200,handle=0
10-12 14:35:17.340 D/Sensors ( 2173): AccelSensor....setDelay, mMinPollDelay=0
10-12 14:35:17.340 D/Sensors ( 2173): AccelSensor....setDelay, mMaxPollDelay=0
10-12 14:35:17.340 D/Sensors ( 2173): AccelSensor....setDelay, delay=200,poll_sysfs_file=
10-12 14:35:17.350 I/BaseActivity( 6394): onResume - com.songbirdnest.philipsplayer.activities.ContentBrowser
10-12 14:35:17.430 I/LockScreenService( 4281): Received Action -- android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON
10-12 14:35:17.450 I/SongListingView( 6394): onResume
10-12 14:35:17.450 V/MediaProvider( 2437): 1
10-12 14:35:17.470 D/SurfaceFlinger( 2173): Screen about to return, flinger = 0x943d8
10-12 14:35:17.480 V/MediaProvider( 2437): 1
10-12 14:35:17.480 I/ContentObserver( 6394): SongListingView: register
10-12 14:35:18.010 V/MediaProvider( 2437): 2
10-12 14:35:18.080 V/MediaProvider( 2437): 2
10-12 14:35:18.090 D/PowerManagerService( 2173): mWifiReconnectTask() +++ enter +++
10-12 14:35:18.090 E/wpa_supplicant( 6372): wpa_driver_priv_driver_cmd failed
10-12 14:35:18.090 D/PowerManagerService( 2173):    info.getSupplicantState()=SCANNING
10-12 14:35:18.090 D/PowerManagerService( 2173): mWifiReconnectTask() --- exit ---
10-12 14:35:18.100 I//system/bin/wpa_supplicant( 6371): ioctl[SIOCSIWPRIV]: Bad address
10-12 14:35:18.170 D/dalvikvm( 4281): GC_CONCURRENT freed 467K, 52% free 2976K/6151K, external 1204K/1228K, paused 3ms+9ms
10-12 14:35:18.360 D/dalvikvm( 4281): GC_CONCURRENT freed 506K, 52% free 2982K/6151K, external 1204K/1228K, paused 3ms+3ms
10-12 14:35:18.420 V/MediaProvider( 2437): 2
10-12 14:35:18.440 V/MediaProvider( 2437): 2
10-12 14:35:18.550 D/dalvikvm( 4281): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 261K, 52% free 2959K/6151K, external 1204K/1228K, paused 65ms
10-12 14:35:18.810 D/dalvikvm( 4281): GC_CONCURRENT freed 510K, 52% free 2982K/6151K, external 1204K/1716K, paused 3ms+7ms
10-12 14:35:18.940 D/dalvikvm( 6394): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 908K, 50% free 3410K/6791K, external 3600K/3877K, paused 83ms
10-12 14:35:18.990 W/InputManagerService( 2173): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@2b2260c8
10-12 14:35:20.739 I/wpa_supplicant( 6372): CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-RESULTS  Ready
10-12 14:35:23.260 I/MediaPlayer( 4281): ----- MediaPlayer start:::
10-12 14:35:23.270 I/OMXPlayer( 2160): Resume player.
10-12 14:35:23.290 D/A2DP    ( 2160): bluetooth_start
10-12 14:35:25.350 D/A2DP    ( 2160): Received BT_RESPONSE - BT_START_STREAM
10-12 14:35:25.350 D/A2DP    ( 2160): Received BT_RESPONSE - BT_NEW_STREAM
10-12 14:35:25.370 E/BluetoothEventLoop.cpp( 2173): event_filter: Received signal org.bluez.AudioSink:Playing from /org/bluez/5644/hci0/dev_58_17_0C_ED_E1_01
10-12 14:35:25.390 E/BluetoothEventLoop.cpp( 2173): event_filter: Received signal org.bluez.AudioSink:PropertyChanged from /org/bluez/5644/hci0/dev_58_17_0C_ED_E1_01
10-12 14:35:25.400 W/AudioFlinger( 2160): write blocked for 2110 msecs, 5 delayed writes, thread 0x52e70
10-12 14:35:25.400 V/FullSound2( 2160): FullSound2_command start
10-12 14:35:25.400 V/FullSound2( 2160):     FullSound2_command cmdCode Case: EFFECT_CMD_SET_VOLUME start
10-12 14:35:25.400 V/FullSound2( 2160):     FullSound2_command cmdCode Case: EFFECT_CMD_SET_VOLUME end, L=1331200, R=1331200
10-12 14:35:25.400 V/FullSound2( 2160): FullSound2_command end...
10-12 14:35:25.400 V/FullSound2( 2160): 
10-12 14:35:25.430 E/BluetoothEventLoop.cpp( 2173): event_filter: Received signal org.bluez.AudioSink:PropertyChanged from /org/bluez/5644/hci0/dev_58_17_0C_ED_E1_01
10-12 14:35:25.440 V/BluetoothEventRedirector( 2363): Received android.bluetooth.a2dp.action.SINK_STATE_CHANGED
10-12 14:35:25.440 D/CachedBluetoothDevice( 2363): onProfileStateChanged: profile A2DP newProfileState 4
10-12 14:35:25.450 D/BluetoothA2dpService( 2173): A2DP state : device: 58:17:0C:ED:E1:01 State:2->4
10-12 14:35:28.010 I/wpa_supplicant( 6372): CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-RESULTS  Ready
10-12 14:35:30.750 D/dalvikvm( 2363): GC_EXPLICIT freed 271K, 49% free 3228K/6215K, external 1158K/1615K, paused 154ms
10-12 14:35:33.610 D/FlurryAgent( 6394): Ending session
10-12 14:35:33.690 D/FlurryAgent( 6394): Continuing previous session
10-12 14:35:35.260 I/wpa_supplicant( 6372): CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-RESULTS  Ready
10-12 14:35:38.330 D/dalvikvm( 2419): GC_CONCURRENT freed 431K, 52% free 2718K/5639K, external 716K/1038K, paused 25ms+2ms
10-12 14:35:40.230 I/OMXPlayer( 2160): Pause player.
10-12 14:35:40.260 D/ALSAModule( 2160): route called for devices 00000000 in mode 0...
10-12 14:35:40.320 V/FullSound2( 2160): FullSound2_command start
10-12 14:35:40.320 V/FullSound2( 2160):     FullSound2_command cmdCode Case: EFFECT_CMD_SET_VOLUME start
10-12 14:35:40.320 V/FullSound2( 2160):     FullSound2_command cmdCode Case: EFFECT_CMD_SET_VOLUME end, L=0, R=0
10-12 14:35:40.320 V/FullSound2( 2160): FullSound2_command end...
10-12 14:35:40.320 V/FullSound2( 2160): 
10-12 14:35:40.420 D/dalvikvm( 4281): GC_CONCURRENT freed 454K, 53% free 2912K/6151K, external 1204K/1716K, paused 2ms+12ms
10-12 14:35:42.250 I/dispd   ( 2030): path:/devices/platform/pmic_battery.1/power_supply/battery
10-12 14:35:42.510 I/wpa_supplicant( 6372): CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-RESULTS  Ready
10-12 14:35:43.330 D/A2DP    ( 2160): a2dp_stop
10-12 14:35:43.330 D/A2DP    ( 2160): bluetooth_stop
10-12 14:35:43.430 D/A2DP    ( 2160): Received BT_RESPONSE - BT_STOP_STREAM
10-12 14:35:43.430 E/BluetoothEventLoop.cpp( 2173): event_filter: Received signal org.bluez.AudioSink:Stopped from /org/bluez/5644/hci0/dev_58_17_0C_ED_E1_01
10-12 14:35:43.440 E/BluetoothEventLoop.cpp( 2173): event_filter: Received signal org.bluez.AudioSink:PropertyChanged from /org/bluez/5644/hci0/dev_58_17_0C_ED_E1_01
10-12 14:35:43.440 E/BluetoothEventLoop.cpp( 2173): event_filter: Received signal org.bluez.AudioSink:PropertyChanged from /org/bluez/5644/hci0/dev_58_17_0C_ED_E1_01
10-12 14:35:43.440 E/BluetoothService( 2173): test1 mBluetoothState=12
10-12 14:35:43.460 V/BluetoothEventRedirector( 2363): Received android.bluetooth.a2dp.action.SINK_STATE_CHANGED
10-12 14:35:43.460 D/CachedBluetoothDevice( 2363): onProfileStateChanged: profile A2DP newProfileState 2
10-12 14:35:43.470 D/BluetoothA2dpService( 2173): A2DP state : device: 58:17:0C:ED:E1:01 State:4->2
10-12 14:35:49.760 I/wpa_supplicant( 6372): CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-RESULTS  Ready
10-12 14:35:51.250 I/dispd   ( 2030): path:/devices/virtual/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:3
10-12 14:35:51.260 E/BluetoothEventLoop.cpp( 2173): event_filter: Received signal org.bluez.Device:PropertyChanged from /org/bluez/5644/hci0/dev_94_63_D1_3B_91_25
10-12 14:35:51.690 I/BtOppRfcommListener( 4261): Accepted connectoin from 94:63:D1:3B:91:25
10-12 14:35:51.690 I/BtOpp Service( 4261): Start Obex Server
10-12 14:35:52.880 I/OMXPlayer( 2160): Loading content: sharedfd://35:0:20052:13
10-12 14:35:52.880 I/OMXPlayer( 2160): LEVEL: 1 FUNCTION: MediaTypeInspect LINE: 1415
10-12 14:35:52.880 I/OMXPlayer( 2160): Can't inspect media content type by subfix.
10-12 14:35:52.990 I/OMXPlayer( 2160): nPreCacheSize = 20052
10-12 14:35:53.220 I/AudioService( 2173):  AudioFocus  requestAudioFocus() from android.media.AudioManager@2b11b330
10-12 14:35:53.220 I/MediaPlayer( 2173): ----- MediaPlayer start:::
10-12 14:35:53.220 I/OMXPlayer( 2160): start player.
10-12 14:35:53.220 D/A2DP    ( 2160): bluetooth_start
10-12 14:35:56.230 W/AudioTrack( 2160): obtainBuffer timed out (is the CPU pegged?) 0x133138 user=00002800, server=00000000
10-12 14:35:56.790 I/OMXPlayer( 2160): Stop Player.
10-12 14:35:57.000 E/A2DP    ( 2160): BT_START_STREAM failed : I/O error(5)
10-12 14:35:57.000 D/A2DP    ( 2160): bluetooth_close
10-12 14:35:57.000 E/A2dpAudioInterface( 2160): a2dp_write failed err: -110
10-12 14:35:57.030 I/wpa_supplicant( 6372): CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-RESULTS  Ready
10-12 14:35:57.050 W/AudioFlinger( 2160): write blocked for 3837 msecs, 6 delayed writes, thread 0x52e70
10-12 14:35:57.060 D/A2DP    ( 2160): bluetooth_init
10-12 14:35:57.730 D/dalvikvm( 4261): GC_EXPLICIT freed 271K, 53% free 2981K/6215K, external 731K/1038K, paused 90ms
10-12 14:35:57.970 I/ActivityManager( 2173): Starting: Intent { dat=content://com.android.bluetooth.opp/btopp/3 flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.android.bluetooth/.opp.BluetoothOppIncomingFileConfirmActivity } from pid 4261
10-12 14:35:57.980 I/BaseActivity( 6394): onPause - com.songbirdnest.philipsplayer.activities.ContentBrowser
10-12 14:35:57.990 I/SongListingView( 6394): onPause
10-12 14:35:57.990 I/ContentObserver( 6394): SongListingView: unregister
10-12 14:35:57.990 I/ContentObserver( 6394): SongListingView-Filter: unregister
10-12 14:35:57.990 I/ContentObserver( 6394): SongListingView-Filter: null cursor
10-12 14:35:58.060 E/A2dpAudioInterface( 2160): a2dp_write failed err: -110
10-12 14:35:58.120 D/A2DP    ( 2160): bluetooth_configure
10-12 14:35:58.120 D/A2DP    ( 2160): Received BT_RESPONSE - BT_GET_CAPABILITIES
10-12 14:35:58.120 D/A2DP    ( 2160): Received BT_RESPONSE - BT_OPEN
10-12 14:35:58.120 D/A2DP    ( 2160): bluetooth_a2dp_hw_params sending configuration:
10-12 14:35:58.120 D/A2DP    ( 2160):   channel_mode: JOINT STEREO
10-12 14:35:58.120 D/A2DP    ( 2160):   frequency: 44100
10-12 14:35:58.120 D/A2DP    ( 2160):   allocation_method: LOUDNESS
10-12 14:35:58.120 D/A2DP    ( 2160):   subbands: 8
10-12 14:35:58.120 D/A2DP    ( 2160):   block_length: 16
10-12 14:35:58.120 D/A2DP    ( 2160):   min_bitpool: 2
10-12 14:35:58.120 D/A2DP    ( 2160):   max_bitpool: 53
10-12 14:35:58.120 D/A2DP    ( 2160): Received BT_RESPONSE - BT_SET_CONFIGURATION
10-12 14:35:58.120 D/A2DP    ( 2160): MTU: 672
10-12 14:35:58.120 D/A2DP    ( 2160): frame_duration: 2902 us
10-12 14:35:58.120 D/A2DP    ( 2160):   allocation=0
10-12 14:35:58.120 D/A2DP    ( 2160):   subbands=1
10-12 14:35:58.120 D/A2DP    ( 2160):   blocks=3
10-12 14:35:58.120 D/A2DP    ( 2160):   bitpool=53
10-12 14:35:58.120 D/A2DP    ( 2160): bluetooth_start
10-12 14:35:58.120 E/A2DP    ( 2160): BT_START_STREAM failed : I/O error(5)
10-12 14:35:58.120 D/A2DP    ( 2160): bluetooth_close
10-12 14:35:58.460 I/ActivityManager( 2173): Displayed com.android.bluetooth/.opp.BluetoothOppIncomingFileConfirmActivity: +454ms
10-12 14:35:59.120 E/A2dpAudioInterface( 2160): a2dp_write failed err: -110
10-12 14:35:59.120 W/AudioTrack( 2160): obtainBuffer timed out (is the CPU pegged?) 0x133138 user=00003c00, server=00001400
10-12 14:35:59.180 D/A2DP    ( 2160): bluetooth_init
10-12 14:35:59.180 D/ALSAModule( 2160): route called for devices 00000000 in mode 0...
10-12 14:35:59.190 I/AudioService( 2173):  AudioFocus  abandonAudioFocus() from android.media.AudioManager@2b11b330
10-12 14:35:59.240 I/BaseActivity( 6394): onResume - com.songbirdnest.philipsplayer.activities.ContentBrowser
10-12 14:35:59.360 I/SongListingView( 6394): onResume
10-12 14:35:59.370 V/MediaProvider( 2437): 1
10-12 14:35:59.400 V/MediaProvider( 2437): 1
10-12 14:35:59.400 I/ContentObserver( 6394): SongListingView: register
10-12 14:35:59.410 W/InputManagerService( 2173): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@2b227768
10-12 14:35:59.970 V/MediaProvider( 2437): 2
10-12 14:36:00.000 E/BluetoothEventLoop.cpp( 2173): event_filter: Received signal org.bluez.AudioSink:Disconnected from /org/bluez/5644/hci0/dev_58_17_0C_ED_E1_01
10-12 14:36:00.010 E/BluetoothEventLoop.cpp( 2173): event_filter: Received signal org.bluez.AudioSink:PropertyChanged from /org/bluez/5644/hci0/dev_58_17_0C_ED_E1_01
10-12 14:36:00.010 E/BluetoothEventLoop.cpp( 2173): event_filter: Received signal org.bluez.AudioSink:PropertyChanged from /org/bluez/5644/hci0/dev_58_17_0C_ED_E1_01
10-12 14:36:00.030 I/dispd   ( 2030): path:/devices/virtual/input/input5/event5
10-12 14:36:00.030 I/EventHub( 2173): Removed device: path=/dev/input/event5 name=AVRCP id=0x10004 (of 0x5) index=6 fd=210 classes=0x1
10-12 14:36:00.030 I/InputReader( 2173): Device removed: id=0x10004, name=AVRCP, sources=00000101
10-12 14:36:00.040 D/BluetoothA2dpService( 2173): A2DP state : device: 58:17:0C:ED:E1:01 State:2->0
10-12 14:36:00.040 V/BluetoothEventRedirector( 2363): Received android.bluetooth.a2dp.action.SINK_STATE_CHANGED
10-12 14:36:00.040 D/CachedBluetoothDevice( 2363): onProfileStateChanged: profile A2DP newProfileState 0
10-12 14:36:00.050 V/FullSound2( 2160): FullSound2_command start
10-12 14:36:00.050 V/FullSound2( 2160):     FullSound2_command cmdCode Case: EFFECT_CMD_CONFIGURE start
10-12 14:36:00.050 V/FullSound2( 2160):     FullSound2_configure start
10-12 14:36:00.050 V/FullSound2( 2160):     FulSound2_Configure : sampling rate   = 44100
10-12 14:36:00.050 V/FullSound2( 2160):     FullSound2_configure End
10-12 14:36:00.050 V/FullSound2( 2160):     FullSound2_command cmdCode Case: EFFECT_CMD_CONFIGURE end
10-12 14:36:00.050 V/FullSound2( 2160): FullSound2_command end...
10-12 14:36:00.050 V/FullSound2( 2160): 
10-12 14:36:00.060 V/MediaProvider( 2437): 2
10-12 14:36:00.070 I/dispd   ( 2030): path:/devices/virtual/input/input5
10-12 14:36:00.180 E/A2dpAudioInterface( 2160): a2dp_write failed err: -110
10-12 14:36:00.270 D/A2DP    ( 2160): a2dp_cleanup
10-12 14:36:00.270 D/A2DP    ( 2160): bluetooth_close
10-12 14:36:00.270 D/A2DP    ( 2160): a2dp_thread finished
10-12 14:36:00.270 I/BluetoothDeviceProfileState( 2173): Entering IncomingA2dp state with: 8
10-12 14:36:00.270 I/BluetoothDeviceProfileState( 2173): Processing command:8
10-12 14:36:00.270 I/BluetoothDeviceProfileState( 2173): Entering ACL Connected state with: 102
```

hcidump shows that the device closes the connection at this time.

Comment: All Bluetooth devices share the same wireless frequency spectrum.  When you do "intensive" Bluetooth communications to one device it will effect all devices in the same area.  The question is can you make your headset a little more forgiving in retrying to communicate before it gives up and just breaks the connection.  Are there any settings like that for your headset?